# What happens if you set an expired session with session_id()?

Tags: php, flash

For my website, i'm using a flash app to allow some stuff that php and just can't do. Therefore i need to have a good medium to check the sessions. My current idea is to add the session into as a get variable on the swf, and check the contents of the session with session_id() in php after i post the image that i'm processing.

However, i'm afraid it might be a security risk. So my question is, does session_id(sessionhere) ignore expired sessions. Or does it renew the session, and still use the data that's inside regardless if it is let's say, 6 months old?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

session_id() just sets the value of the session cookie variable. It doesn't check if there's a session of that name or not - that's session_start()'s job. Setting the id, however, does force PHP to send a "set cookie" header with the new id, even if you did `session_id(session_name())` which works out to a null-op overall.

If you did `session_id('constantstring')`, then everyone who used your site would share the same session.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. Here's the situation in a simpler way:

1. User logs in on website.
2. User loads flash app for image processing
3. User saves image.
4. Image gets bound to user account.

The swf gets another session therefore i have to feed it one, and add it to the request of the save. What the question is, does it IGNORE or actually use the session if it is expired. As in, the session that is set on the user side, and is now being used by the swf to save the image to their account after processing.

Comment: yes, php'll use the session ID as provided by the user, creating a brand new session if one already doesn't exist under that ID (presuming the id value fits into the regular session ID naming scheme).

Comment: In other words, it's not a safe way to check a users session validity then.

Comment: Nope. anyone can slap a session ID into their cookie file and take over someone else's session, if they know what that user's ID is.